# .bat script doesnt work on Japanese user computer

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I created a script for my company in the US and everything works, I sent this to a user in Japan and the majority of the script functions correctly. However when a robocopy kicks in the Japanese computer errors out.

The error:

> 'robocopy' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 “robocopy” was not recognized as patch file, controllable program, internal command, or external command.
>   操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
>
> ** Error **
>
> 'robocopy' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
>   操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。“robocopy” was not recognized as patch file, controllable program, internal command, or external command.
>   続行するには何かキーを押してください . . . Press any key to continue…

The code:

```
robocopy C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4\_Upload C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Color_Check_v1.4\_Data\_Propagation
```

I am reading about 'code pages' as it seems there is a language issue. I am not sure if that is the actual issue. If that is the problem, how does one determine what code page to use for a user?

Comment: The error says that computer doesn't have `robocopy` program. It's probably Windows XP. Suggest them to extract it from the official [Windows Resource Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).

Comment: Brilliant. I was sure they worked on Windows 7. Thanks so much for the input - i will see if this is the issue.

Comment: @wOxxOm the user is running Windows 7 enterprise. Do you still think they need to add the robocopy command?

Comment: This is very strange. There's something wrong on their PC. Ask them to find `robocopy` using Windows Explorer.

Comment: @wOxxOm will do thanks for quick prompt. Would having the user type 'help' into the command prompt be a sufficient search?

Comment: I see no relation between `help` and `robocopy`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry I must be missing something. I was under the impression typing help into command prompt provides a list of available commands. How would you go about finding robocopy using Windows Explorer?

Comment: You can find a lot of examples in google, even videos. Probably in Japanese as well :-)

Comment: @wOxxOm the user has confirmed "C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe". This is very strange - any other suggestions?

Comment: What output from `set pathext`? And from `where robocopy`? Please `Copy`&`Paste` from an open `cmd` window (no screenshot). Try `robocopy.exe` or even `C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe` instead of bare `robocopy`. FYI, my settings is as follows: `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW` (note no spaces) and `C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe`.

Comment: @JosefZ Using command C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe did the trick. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: I'd recommend your user shall find why and adjust his Windows installation…